# How to find google place ID?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-api

I've tried using https://developers.google.com/places/place-id but the business but my business isn't showing up in the auto search like it is when I search it in Google Maps.

Here is the Google Business page: https://plus.google.com/b/107291386872307941191/

How do I find it if it isn't appearing on the developer search?

Comment: `ChIJo5zQb3xqsYkRLGQfN7XF8SY` (returned by [**places-textsearch**](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search#TextSearchRequests) for `CUT BACK BARBERSHOP/SOLA SALONS SUITE 15`)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder)

Searching on your address I get the id ChIJvYKzbnxqsYkRdGzAWw_XZrY

Comment: That only works for the address, but its not working for the business. It's not showing the review.